# Scramblies in Codewars

Tags: python, python-3.x

i've been continuing to practice my python skill in codewars and i need some help again.
It's from codewars called Scramblies

> Complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false.
>
> Notes:
>
> Only lower case letters will be used (a-z). No punctuation or digits
> will be included. Performance needs to be considered

I've coded and theres a few test errors that says

> Testing for two strings up to 600000 characters.
>
> It should work with random inputs too: True should equal False

Here is my code

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    # your code here
    text = ""
    for i in s2:
        if (i in s1) and i.islower() and i.isalpha():
            text += i
        else:
            continue
    if text == s2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I don't get it. I've test the code in idle and it's return the right answer. Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: What is an example where the code does something different than it is supposed to?

Comment: I guess `scramble('a', 'aa')` returns `True`, but it should return `False`?

Comment: Create a `Counter` of both strings. if the first strings numbers are all lower then the 2nd and all letters of the 2nd occure in the 1st Counter you can else not so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
def scramble(str1,str2):
    c1 = dict(Counter(str1))
    c2 = dict(Counter(str2))
    return all((c2[ch] <= c1.get(ch,0) for ch in c2))
```

Comment: A Counter is already a dict, so you don't need those `dict()` wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nifty thing you can do with `Counter`: subtraction. And the unary plus operator removes keys that don't have a strictly positive count.

Here is how you can use that with a single instance of `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
def scramble(s1, s2):
    c = Counter(s2)
    c.subtract(s1)
    return not +c
```

Or, if you use two `Counter` objects, then the subtraction operator can be used, which also only retains keys in the result that have counts that are strictly positive:

```
from collections import Counter
def scramble(s1, s2):
    return not (Counter(s2) - Counter(s1))
```

But this is slightly less efficient than the previous approach.

Comment: Nice analysis,  +1 for the *single instance of Counter* and ```+c```.