# Codewars Scramblies in Python

Tags: python

This is a reference to codewars' notorious [scramblies](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048/train/python) I can't understand the reason why my straightforward code's performance is slow (above 12000ms according to codewars tests); I'm not passing the kata and I'm upset.
The code should check two strings, and if the first string contains all the letters the second have, it should return True; for example:

- scramble('rkqodlw', 'world') ==> True
- scramble('cedewaraaossoqqyt', 'codewars') ==> True
- scramble('katas', 'steak') ==> False

```
def scramble(s1,s2):
    for n in s2:
        if (s1.find(n)!=-1):
            s1=s1.replace(n,"",1)
            s2=s2.replace(n,"",1)
    if s2=="": return True
    else: return False
```

Comment: Please use your own words to explain, in the question itself, what the code needs to do. Also, what does "above 12000" mean? 12000 *of what*? Are big numbers better or worse? What is your goal for the performance?

Comment: I corrected, it's above 12000ms and the server gives a stderr for timing out

Comment: BTW, you can simplify that `if...else` stuff to `return s2 == ""`

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks.  Noted.  How about this another then - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859438/

Answer (score 2):

It's just that there's a much easier way of doing it.

The basic steps that you can do are

1. count the number of each character in s1. Use a dict .
2. Go through each character in s2. Make sure it either exists in s1, or if there are any s1 characters left

The way you did it, the find and replace algorithms each have implicit loops and that makes it slow. With the algorithm given below. There are no implicit loops.

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    p = {}
    for x in s1:
        if(not x in p):
            p[x] = 1
        else:
            p[x] += 1
    for x in s2:
        if((not x in p) or (p[x] == 0)):
            return False
        elif (x in p):
            p[x] -= 1
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

The string replacements are unnecessary. You can do this using a Counter as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

def scramble(s1, s2):
    d = Counter(s1)
    for c in s2:
        if d.get(c) in {None, 0}:
            return False
        d[c] -= 1
    return True
```

If you don't want to use Counter then it's simply:

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    d = {}
    for c in s1:
        d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
    for c in s2:
        if d.get(c) in {None, 0}:
            return False
        d[c] -= 1
    return True
```

In terms of performance there's very little (if anything) between either solution. The Python pedants will tell you to use Counter because that's what it's there for

Comment: This can be simplified to just `not Counter(s2) - Counter(s1)`, and starting with python 3.10, `Counter(s2) <= Counter(s1)`.

Comment: Also note that you didn't really answer the question. OP wants to know why their code is slow.

Comment: @Aran-Fey It's all the unnecessary string replacement that I allude to in my first sentence

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `Counter.subtract` method https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxlj0FrwzAMhe-B_AfdYoMpy46DnQb7Bb2VMlzFgRDbaiSF0H8_uw1boTfxPT29p5EpAVKMAXWiLDClK7HCF61ZA7dN2wxePXyCaRsA02EYwubZexKhZblp56BDukMp85HXYN1jdy7OyjrR4OcyfPsofyrPCw1xq_pGHIcns73nhhEE2adLDEZ6B_JuP6oVAEufvaEpdIcHWS_KHrVs74yDrpwhkxY5kegPUkqUTW9Pb-dTf65BIzE87jtghClDfXmPuvKU1fzL7qWT_QW_4l6K&lang=python